# Getting the name of a JRadioButton in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to get the names of all selected JRadioButtons from my graphics interface. As such I create the allFacilities array in which I include all of my JRadioButtons.

The first for loop serves to find the number of selected radio buttons.

The second for loop aspires to get the name of each selected button.

When checking what the .getName() returns: 
    `System.out.println("A##" + button.getName());`, only null is returned for all cases.

Here is my code:

```
    JRadioButton[] allFacilities = {restaurant, laundry, parking};
    int selectedFacilitiesCounter = 0;
    for(JRadioButton check : allFacilities) {
        if(check.isSelected()) {
            selectedFacilitiesCounter += 1;
        }
    }
    String[] selectedFacilities = new String[selectedFacilitiesCounter];
    int index = 0;
    for(JRadioButton button : allFacilities) {
        if(button.isSelected()) {
            System.out.println("A##" + button.getName());
            switch(button.getName()) {
                case "restaurant":
                    selectedFacilities[index] = "restaurant";
                    break;
                case "laundry":
                    selectedFacilities[index] = "laundry";
                    break;
                case "parking":
                    selectedFacilities[index] = "parking";
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Facility Not Found");
            } 
            index += 1;          
        }
     }
```

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can solve my problem?

Comment: By "name" you mean the displayed text? Did you try `getText()`? If you want to work with names you need first to call `setName(string)` and then you can get it later.

Comment: I'll try the setName(). I mean the name of the JRadioButton variable as in the ones displayed when I initialize the array.

Comment: Use  `button.getText()` instead.

Comment: If you want the name of the variable, take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744226/java-reflection-how-to-get-the-name-of-a-variable

Comment: You shouldn't do it with the name of the variables itself. The variable names are not preserved in compilation and there's no reason to do it anyway. You have to use stored data.

Comment: I agree with @user1803551. Just go with getText and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I used getText() and setName() and both worked fine. I think I'll proceed with getText() though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting text value from a jButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082051/getting-text-value-from-a-jbutton)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you want is this:

```
    JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton("test");
    System.out.println(button.getText());
```

Which will print `test`.

The method `getName` retrieves the `name` of the component, which you should've set with `setName`, which I believe you didn't.